# Setting size parameter ES laravel

Tags: laravel, elasticsearch

I have a simple part of code in laravel Elasticquent:

```
    $laws = Law::searchByQuery([
        'multi_match' => [
            'query' => Input::get('query', ''),
            'fields' => [ "law_name", "law_year", "law_raw_content"],
        ],
    ]);
```

I want to set a size parameter. I tried:

```
    $laws = Law::searchByQuery([
        'multi_match' => [
            'query' => Input::get('query', ''),
            'fields' => [ "law_name", "law_year", "law_raw_content"],
            'size' => 100,
        ],
    ]);
```

But no luck. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the Elasticquent documentation](https://github.com/adamfairholm/Elasticquent#searching), the `searchByQuery` function takes the following parameters (see [source here](https://github.com/adamfairholm/Elasticquent/blob/b885455305bea34bb5bd922bdab0dea730def58e/src/ElasticquentTrait.php#L244)):

- `query` - Your ElasticSearch Query
- `aggregations` - The Aggregations you wish to return.
- `sourceFields` - Limits returned set to the selected fields only
- `limit` - Number of records to return
- `offset` - Sets the record offset (use for paging results)
- `sort` - Your sort query

In your call, you simply need to include the `$limit` parameter (fourth parameter) in addition to your query (first parameter). Do it like this instead:

```
$laws = Law::searchByQuery([
    'multi_match' => [
        'query' => Input::get('query', ''),
        'fields' => [ "law_name", "law_year", "law_raw_content"]
    ],
], null, null, 100);
                ^
                |
        add the size here
```